# Don't show question down-vote "comment notice" after up-voting a comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, down-votes

When down-voting a question with low reputation, the following notice is displayed:

> Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be
>   improved.

Good advice, and even better it doesn't show this notice if you make a comment first - then down-vote.

However, sometimes somebody beats me to the punch and adds a comment explaining their down-vote. If I agree with their reason, I can up-vote their comment and down-vote the question myself. However, the notification above should not display in this scenario.

Comment: How would you differentiate *a general comment upvote* and *a comment upvote which clarifies the reason for your downvote*?!

Comment: @R.J There is no differentiation for adding comments either, which prevents the notice from appearing. It is "good faith" that the comment (either originating from the electorate, or up-voted by) is regarding the vote.

Answer (score 2):

There are too many assumptions for this to work. For example, what if a user upvotes a comment which was not explaining a down vote - such as a comment between two other users discussing the post.

Moreover, the suggestion to comment is in place to encourage new users to provide feedback. Upvoting a comment is not as strong of feedback and the upvote could easily be pulled once the downvote were made. There could be a case made that the comment could be deleted, but it will still show in the user's inbox.

All in all, this seems to be too much of an edge case to handle.

Comment: I think "this seems to be too much of an edge case to handle" is the right answer even if I theoretically thought it was a good suggestion (which I don't, for the reasons you pointed out).

Comment: Odd as it may, I ended up up voting both Q & A here.